# How can I use a folder name other than ‘functions’ for the cloud functions in my firebase project?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have my source organized in a way that makes **functions** an awkward name for the location of my cloud functions source. I'm using the **"main"** property in the package.json to specify the source file but the deploy tool looks in **functions** for package.json. I've read all the docs available for the config file but don't see anything for the cloud functions.

The **init** command doesn't even add a section in the config file.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had this same issue and found the answer by reading the source code for firebase-tool. (but not in the documentation!)

You can add this to firebase.json to rename the functions folder:

```
"functions": {
    "source": "<your-folder-name>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to use project root as cloud functions folder, add `.` to `firebase.json`

```
"functions": {
    "source": ".",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#deploy_functions